# laravel 5; redirect to previous section after store or view

Tags: redirect, laravel-5, routes

I think this is a basic problem or question, but i can't find any solution that solves this problem, so probably i'm searching in the wrong way or on the wrong keywords.

I have a bunch of articles in my DB, and there are a number of ways to read/edit them on the site. 
- The visitor can see them in a list, click on them and read the whole article
- The registered users can see them in the same list, but click on them to read or edit the article
- The admin can see a different list (an different view), and edit or delete them
and i'm sure i will come up with some other ways to read or edit the articles or other data.

The point is, that if a visitor or user had read or edited the article, i want them to return to their own index of articles, but if an admin has read or edited the article i want him to go back to the admin-index.

So from the start i have a number of routes:

```
Route::get('/article'... will display the index of articles
Route::get('/article/{name}'... will display an article
Route::get('/article/{name}/edit'... will display the edit form for the article
Route::post('/article/{name}'... will update the article
```

And for the admin:

```
Route::get('/admin/article'... will display the index of article
Route::get('/admin/article/{name}'... will display an article
Route::get('/admin/article/{name}/edit'... will display the edit form for the article
Route::post('/admin/article/{name}'... will update the article
```

But..Route::post('/article/{name}' and Route::post('/admin/article/{name} should point to the same function to update the data, and that function should redirect to different routes, in this case *Route::get('/article'* and *Route::get('/admin/article'*

I really dont want to write 2 different routines to store or update the data in the database, that are in fact the same, except for the 'redirect'-line after updating or storing.

My first thought was to make 2 routes, with two entries in my controller that each call the same routine that saves the data, and return where i can redirect, but then i would have to use different 'actions' in my form. That would mean i would have to make 2 forms that are the same, except for the 'action'-line.

Whatever i do, i would have to redirect somewhere based on the section of my site where i was before i started to read or edit my data.

I read something about the 'back()'-function, but that won't help me because i want to be able to read an article, and then choose to edit it, then return back to my index.

I hope i was able to explain what i want to do, and i'm sure i'm not the only one looking for this, but again, i failed in finding a right solution.

What is het best way to achieve this?!?

Answer (score 0):

I would just separate the controllers between normal users and admin users. This way your code will stay clean and understandable.

You could for example make the following folder structure:

```
app
 - Http
  - Controllers
   - Admin
   - User
```

Don't forget to change the namespace in your controllers.

If you really want to stick with the same controller for both users then you need to make some kind of if else statement to see what kind of user your are dealing with and redirect on that outcome. Do you have some kind of role structure in your application?

Comment: I do have a controller for the article. In my opinion thats the most clean. There is also a role structure.
But the thing is that in my article-controller, when i redirect after saving, i have to redirect to a route depending on where i came from. How can i see which part of my site called the article-controller?

Comment: Just make a user article controller and a admin article controller. You only have 2 options regarding the redirect right? User or admin? point your admin route to the admin article controller and the user to the user article controller. You could also make some sort of if else statement based on the role and then redirect to the correct location

Comment: Thats one possibility but not what I am looking for.  I will need this 'trick' for otter model aswell. So I am definately looking for an option to redirect conditionally according to the section I came from or according to the current URL.

Comment: Maybe you can use the URL helper from Laravel to accomplish what you want. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#urls